# How to host binary image in mongodb and show it on the client?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, binary

I am sending the from client to server using form data. I am using file input in html.

This is my front end

```
const image = event.target.files[0]
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('image', image)
fetch('http://localhost:8080/image', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData
})
```

For the back end I am using multer and express.

```
app.post('/image', multer().single("image"), (req, res) => {
    database.collection('test').insertOne({image: req.file})
})
```

To get back data I am not doing anything fancy

```
app.get('/image', async (req, res) => {
    const response = await database.collection('test').find({}).toArray()
    res.send(response)
})
```

Now, how do I show that image on the client side?

I actually tried to convert the file to blob and blob to url. But the image is broken.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to hosting and displaying images for the client, there are actually many different ways to do it. Here's an example that you may find helpful: you can convert the image the user uploads to a base64 string and save it as a string on the backend. Then, when you want to display the image on the client side, you can simply use the following code:

```
<img src='${//base64 string that was saved on the backend}' />
```

However, if you prefer to save the image as a file, it might be useful to have some more context on how you are fetching the image and converting it to a blob, i recently create a post about getting an image from api [here](https://wypratama.my.id/blog/daily-dev-problem-downloading-images-from-an-api-and-handling-binary-data-correctly-in-javascript/) that probably helpful. In general, to make sure that the file is fetched as a blob, you can use something like this with axios:

```js
const response = await axios.get(IMAGE_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'image/png',
    },
    responseType: 'blob', // Set the responseType to 'blob'
  });
```

and if you use fetch you probably want to do something like:

```js
const response = await fetch(IMAGE_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'image/png',
    }
  });
const blob = response.blob()
```

Depending on the case you might be able to convert to base64 if you want to display the image.

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch thank you for the input i tried to add context to my reply, hope that make it clearer.